# Artifacting/shaking occuring for THREE.Sprite() when animating orthographic camera

Tags: three.js, sprite, orthographic

I've gotten sprites to work fine in my game engine, but I'm noticing some odd issues when moving the camera. Mainly, the sprites' pixels kind of 'shake' or go 'wavey' when the camera moves. You can see an example of this here (please watch in HD) http://youtu.be/om3EhKsGd9M

I'm setting the following properties on my sprite texture and sprite material, and my textures are 64 x 64 pixels in size:

```
spriteTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
spriteTexture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;

var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial(
{
    map:sheet,
    useScreenCoordinates:true,
    transparent:true,
    side:THREE.DoubleSide,
});
```

Any ideas on a solution for this issue? I'd wager that this is somehow related to how the sprites are rendered when mapped into 3D space.

Comment: I have not found a solution to this exact issue (perhaps there isn't one) but I've gone back to trilinear filtering and am now using https://github.com/phoboslab/js-hqx on my sprites, they look pretty good now, and there's no shaking really.